# Remove a Widget when pressed in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, widget

Im making a App that creates widgets on the go and I need them to get removed when the User clicks on them. Is there any such self destroy function in kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put something like:

```
self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```

in a `on_touch_up()` method for the widget.